# create a setup file for a project Borland C++ Builder 5

Tags: installation, c++builder, borland-c++

I'm helping out a friend developing a small project and he is using Borland C++ Builder 5.

We're done with the development but I'm not sure how to create a setup file that any user can use to install the program on their computer. Instead of just sending the executable that was compiled I'm sure there should be a way to create a proper setup file.

Any ideas? I know this program is a bit old.

Thanks
Hamster

Comment: [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org).

Comment: Thanks! I was searching around and saw this... will give it a try!